# Javascript Animation before/after countdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to add a countdown, that fades in when page is fully load, and after it hits 0 to fade out and be replaced with another text (fade in as well), I want to do it by myself but, can someone give me some indications? Thanks.

Comment: As you said "**I want to do it by myself...**" therefore I'm telling you that these methos `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, `.fadeOut()` `.fadeIn()` `if else` will help you to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Element.animate()` to animate multiple properties and `.onfinish` to perform task when animation is finished.

```js
let options = {
  opacity: [0, 1],
  color: ['transparent', 'green'],
  background: ['#fff', '#cb0']
};

let settings = { 
  duration: 2000,
  iterations: 1,
  fill: 'forwards'
};

const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.animate(options, settings)
.onfinish = () => {
  for (const key in options) {
    options[key].reverse();
  }
  div.animate(options, settings)
  .onfinish = () => {
    delete options.background;
    for (const key in options) {
      options[key].reverse();
    }
    div.textContent = 'done';
    div.animate(options, settings);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 95vh;
}
div {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 95vw;
  height: 95vh;
  background: '#fff';
}
```

```html
<div>animating</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot, but why you used let keyword?