# Alternatives to callback functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions:

```
fadeOutBox();
fadeInInfoBlock();
```

And I want to run the 2nd one (`fadeInInfoBlock`) ONLY once the 1st one (`fadeOutBox`) finishes.

Is a callback function the only/best way to do this?

Is there any other way to run a function after another function has completed?

EDIT: other code added here:

Here is what I have going on - working on consolidating multiple redundant functions into one function, but currently I have functions for each of 12 boxes (divs) to add listeners for mouseenter/leave and then I have setInterval loops to increment/decrement the opacity to fade boxes on and off.

Add the listeners:

```
var box01 = document.getElementById("grid01");
box01.addEventListener("mouseenter", fadeOutBoxesFadeInInfoBlock01);
box01.addEventListener("mouseleave", fadeInBoxesFadeOutInfoBlock01);
infoBlock01.style.zIndex = -1; // THIS PUTS DIV AT THE BACK OF THE STACK, SO THE MOUSEENTER CAN TOUCH THE GRIDBOX
infoBlock01.style.opacity = 0;
```

Next functions run other functions that do the opacity fade loops:

```
function fadeOutBoxesFadeInInfoBlock01() {
setTimeout(function() { fadeOut01(); }, 200);
setTimeout(function() { fadeInInfoBlock01(); }, 200);
```

}

```
function fadeInBoxesFadeOutInfoBlock01() {
setTimeout(function() { fadeIn01(); }, 200);
setTimeout(function() { fadeOutInfoBlock01(); }, 100);
```

}

I added the setTimeouts to try to handle mouse movements that are too fast. The code works well if user moves mouse slowly. This is the main issue I'm having - I think I need to completely finish the fadeouts/fadeins before I add the event listeners back to the boxes. Thinking this will better handle the mouse moving too fast over the boxes.

Here is the fadeOut loop for box 1 (again, I have 11 more of these for each other box-haven't figured out how to consolidate into one function yet:

```
function fadeOut01() {

removeListeners();
var op = 1;  // initial opacity
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (op <= 0.1){
        clearInterval(timer);

    }
    box02.style.opacity = op;
    box03.style.opacity = op;
    box04.style.opacity = op;
    box05.style.opacity = op;
    box06.style.opacity = op;
    box07.style.opacity = op;
    box08.style.opacity = op;
    box09.style.opacity = op;
    box10.style.opacity = op;
    box11.style.opacity = op;
    box12.style.opacity = op;

    op -= op * 0.1;
}, 20);

setTimeout(function() {addListeners(); }, 1000);
```

}

And to fade in the infoBlocks:

```
function fadeInInfoBlock01() {

    infoBlock01.style.zIndex = 0; // THIS PUTS DIV AT TOP OF THE STACK, SO THE MOUSEENTER CAN TOUCH THE GRIDBOX

    var infoBlockOpacity = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (infoBlockOpacity >= 1){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    infoBlock01.style.opacity = infoBlockOpacity;
    infoBlockOpacity += 0.1;
    }, 30);
```

}

Comment: Or `await` a `Promise`

Comment: only if your first function has some async code, else anyways they will run one after the other without you doing anything

Comment: What is the code inside fadeOutBox()? It has some async trigger i think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**async**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[**await**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
async function runInOrder(){
    await fadeOutBox(); 
    await fadeInInfoBlock();
}
```

Comment: Make sure the first function returns a Promise first, ofc

Comment: @CertainPerformance what do you mean by that . ?  await converts value to resolved promised if the return value is not a promise.

Comment: You can `await` non-Promises, but unless the called function actually returns a Promise, the `await` will resolve immediately, so the next function will be called immediately, which is almost certainly undesirable

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh yeah that makes sense :) thanks for pointing out mate :) from question it seemed obvious to me that function are async and returning promise. but it's good point to know

Answer (score 1):

No code besides the function calls appear at the question.

The only requirement is to call the functions in a specific order

> And I want to run the 2nd one (`fadeInInfoBlock`) ONLY after the 1st
>   one (`fadeOutBox`) finishes

Given the requirement and the code at the question, one approach would be to execute the second function at the last line of the first function.

```
function fadeOutBox() {
  // do stuff
  fadeInInfoBlock()
}

fadeOutBox()
```

Comment: This is the simple approach my tiny brain is searching for.  I don't quite get the whole async/await/promise thing yet, and callback() seems to have added complexity for me. Have read several explanations on it, but it is over my head at the current time.  But...in this example, how do I guarantee that the commands in fadeOutBox (basically a setInterval function that runs a loop decrementing opacity of the box/div), finishes completely before fadeInInfoBlock will run? My code is a mess right now, and I'm trying to consolidate multiple redundant  functions to one, but I will post it.

Comment: @warlock7 You can use an `if` statement to check if `opacity` of the element is equal to `0`, if true, `break` the loop, call `clearInteval()`, execute `fadeInInfoBox()`. An alternative approach could be to use `Element.animate()` of Web Animations API where `.onfinish` can be utilized, e.g., see [Javascript Animation before/after countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54491077/)

Comment: @warlock7 Re code at updated question, as suggested, would consider using `Element.animate()`

Answer (score 0):

Please convert the function to promise

```
  function fadeOutBox(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   //True statement
    resolve('true')
   });
  }
```

Type I

```
fadeOutBox.then(function(value) {
 console.log(value);
 fadeInInfoBlock();
 })
```

Type II

```
async function syncFn(){
    await fadeOutBox(); 
    await fadeInInfoBlock();
}
```

Make sure the fadeInInfoBlock will also be a promise function if not don't use await